# dart constructor copyWith argument shows null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable `title` which I initialised with a string value.

```
class NameState{
 List name;
 var title = 'this is a default one'; 
 NameState({this.title,this.name});

 NameState copyWith({title, name}) {

     print(title); // this one should be null as there is no data.
     print(this.title); // null => why this one null as i have title defined


    return new NameState(
        title: title ?? this.title, 
        name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }
}
```

Here my `title` variable has a value. but if I don't pass any value for title in the constructor, the value of `this.title` become null. How can I get the current value `this is a default one` in `this.title` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this

```
NameState({this.title = 'this is a default one', this.name});
```

instead of

```
 NameState({this.title,this.name});
```

Comment: Here is a problem. Lets say I am calling the constructor from 3 places. 

for default it has value. 

for second call lets say I replaced it with a value. 

and for 3 time, i won't pass any value. so now i should get my second passed value not the first one. 

so it like this 
1. first call default value = 'this is a default one'
2. second call replace it = 'changed value'
3. now i am not passing anything. it's null. but i don't want to assign null. i want to use it's current value. so current value is `changed value`

how can I do this?

Comment: What are you passing in 1st call?

Comment: initial value 'this is a default one'

Comment: 1st pass --> "this is a default one" , 2nd pass --> "Changed value", 3rd pass --> nothing, and to whom you are passing this, `NameState` constructor or `copyWith` method?